# Can some one tell me what this notation means : N^|| → 

Tags: differential

M stands for a mechanism and N is for all possible natural numbers. I cannot figure out is X the size of the data set or not ?

Comment: Give a bit of context making clear what "mechanism" means, please.

Comment: [Here's what I see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEon0.jpg) Please use MathJax (a type of $\LaTeX$).

Comment: [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) will help you find the code for certain symbols in $\LaTeX$.

Comment: I figured it out. I will use MathJax next time while posting questions :)

Answer (score 0):

First: $|X|$ is probably the number of elements of $X$, so let's assume that's true and set $k = |X|$. Then $N^{|X|}$ is the set of $k$-tuples of natural numbers

If $M:\Bbb{N}^{|X|}\rightarrow \Bbb{R}$, then $M$ is a function that maps a $k$-tuple of natural numbers into the set of real numbers.